# c# set pixel at specific point using pointers

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

i would like to set a pixel at a specific point but without using the slow `SetPixel()` method.

In the regular way,all i have to do is for example :`bmp.SetPixel(120, 53, Color.Red);`

but now when i use `LockBits` and pointers, it seems like i have to pass all the image bounds and cant set a pixel in a specific location.

this is my code

```
private unsafe void ChangePX(Bitmap bmp)
    {


        bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);


        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;

        int stride = bmData.Stride;


        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;

        for(int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)

        {

            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;


            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            {

                if (x==120 &&y==53)
                {//found the position.
                    p[0]=255;
                    p[1]=255;
                    p[2]=255;
                    p[3]=1;
                }


                p += 4;

            }



        bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);      


    }
```

As you see here im looping trough the image to find the specific position but i would like to set it directly without looping.
But i **dont want**  to use the classic `SetPixel` method because i have to set the pixels in many points.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lockbits is 10-20 times faster than setpixel, but for a few single pixels (let alone one) the setting up of the lockbits data will probably eat up the gain..

Comment: @Taw it's won't be always few pixels. .sometimes it can get up to 500-600 pixels. Still `SetPixel ()`?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe not. Sounds borderline to me.. But measuring will tell you if it really makes a difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in a bitmap is padded at the end so the next row starts at a 4-byte boundary. `bmData.Stride` contains the size of such a padded row.

A bitmap also contains header information, such as the pixel format and the size of the image (unpadded). `bmData.Scan0` contains the address of the first byte of pixel data.

So considering each row is `bmData.Stride` bytes wide, row `y` starts at:

```
bmData.Scan0 + (y * bmData.Stride)
```

Each pixel is assumed to be stored in 4 bytes, so to find the first byte of the pixel data for column `x` in row `y`, you multiply it by 4:

```
bmData.Scan0 + (y * bmData.Stride) + (x * 4)
```

Then you can directly point to that address if you want:

```
byte* p = (byte*)bmData.Scan0 + (y * bmData.Stride) + (x * 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* directly address a pixel. Given the dimensions and the stride (assuming you always have 4 bytes per pixel), the address of one pixel is:

```
byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
p += (y * stride) + (x * 4);
```

Why?

Every row contains `stride` bytes, so to get to row `y` you need to add `y * stride` bytes. Each pixel on x-direction has 4 bytes, so if you add `4 * x` you are at pixel `x` in the current row.